# Minimum seperation of moving objects doubt

Tags: classical-mechanics, kinematics, calculus, relative-motion

Let there be $2$ objects $P_1$(initial velocity **$u$** $ms^{-1}$ & acceleration **$a$** $ms^{-2}$) & $P_2$ (initial velocity $U$ $ms^{-1}$ & acceleration $A$ $ms^{-2}$) initially separated by distance of $x_0$ metre.

Relative displacement, $D$ at time $t$ is given by
$$D(t)=x_0+Ut+\frac{At^2}{2} - ut - \frac{at^2}{2}$$

If we differentiate them wrt time then we get
$$\frac{d}{dt}D(t)=U + At - u - at$$

When $\frac{d}{dt}D(t)=0$, then either the distance between them is maximum or minimum. And we get

$$U + At - u - at = 0$$
$$\implies U + At = u + at$$

My book says that

> IN MOST OF THE CASES at minimum distance, $v_1 = v_2$.

What I wrote above was my derivation of that statement. But I think this value can correspond to the maxima also. So why is it that we are considering it the minimum value?

Please explain.

Thanks:)

Comment: Are we accounting for collision here? I mean let's say the two particles are moving towards each other then the separation between them reduces and at one point becomes zero. What happens after that, do they collide and revert back or they resume their motion as if nothing happened?

Comment: @Shivam Singh Aswal If the particles collide then that time will be the required time. If the particles will never collide then the time required for minimum seperation.

Comment: But if the particles collide then the condition you mentioned wont be true.